# Prestashop Facebook Addon - error during instalation

Tags: facebook, module, prestashop, add-on, internal-server-error

I have e-comerce shop running on prestashop engine. Iam trying to install Prestashop Facebook addon from Prestashop addons. My problem is that, during installation Iam getting error from the linked picture.

I will be gratefull for any advice!
[image]

I downloaded zip file and when Iam trying to install it by Module Manager in presta office. My problem is that, during installation Iam getting error from the linked picture.

I tried to download new zip from github repository but Iam still getting the same error. Also I tried to change permissions of folders and files on the server but didnt work for me.

As CBroe recomended I checked error log and I got this:
[image]

When I delete the folder of ps_facebook from module folder via FTP I can see Prestashop Facebook module i Catalog but when Iam clicking on install Iam getting error like this:

Error! The exception thrown by the module ps_facebook podczas install. The file "/home/fbshopplce/www/modules/ps_facebook/config/admin/../common/api.yml" does not contain valid YAML: Unable to parse at line 36 (near "[[") in /home/fbshopplce/www/modules/ps_facebook/config/admin/../common/api.yml (which is being imported from "/home/fbshopplce/www/modules/p

I checked the api.yml file in YAML checker and everything seems to be fine.

Iam runnning out of idea. Please help me guys.

Comment: The first thing you always need to do when you get a 500, is go and check what the error log has to say.

Comment: Try to upload the module by FTP.